# Is there an IPSec stack which I can use with lwIP

Tags: c, rtos, lwip, ipsec

I am developing an embedded device based on OpenRTOS and lwIP (network stack).

I would like to add IPSec support to the device.
Any known IPSec stacks (open source or commercial) which works with lwIP?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/tinytux/embeddedipsec)...Good luck!

Comment: Thanks vlp, I saw that, the code is a bit old from 2003,  however it has a limited support for IPSec. it support tunnel mode only. whereas I need transport mode.